# How to Disable Outlook Button While opening outlook MSG file

Tags: .net

I am opening outlook .MSG files using System Diagnostic process here is my code below

```
Process oFileProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
oFileProcess.StartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\OutlookFile.MSG");
oFileProcess.Start();
```

After execution of this code MSG file is opening with Outlook but my requirement is i want to disable all buttons of Outlook like Send/Recieve, Reply, Forward .... when a file is opened with my dotnet application.

How can  i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a System.Diagnostics.Process object to launch outlook, use the "Microsoft Outlook 10.0/11.0 Object Library" COM object to control Outlook. Might be difficult to hide the buttons that you want but in theory it could be possible.